# How to set and get Boolean value from a asp.net hidden field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field, boolean-operations

I have a hidden field. Where I need to set a Boolean value intitially. After some operation I need to update the hidden filed value using JavaScript. But we can only store string value in hidden field. 
How to set/get Boolean value in hidden field?

Any Idea how to implement it?

Comment: You need to `parse` or `convert` string to bool

Answer (score 8):

As you correctly noticed - you can only store String in HiddenField Value.
To determine boolean value in Code Behind - you should Convert String Value to Bool.

For example:

```
bool val = Convert.ToBoolean(HiddenField1.Value);
```

To set Hidden Field value:

```
HiddenField1.Value = val.ToString();
```

in JavaScript - you can accomplish this by using:

```
var hiddenFieldValueString = document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value;
var val = (hiddenFieldValueString === "true");
```

setting new Hidden Field Value:

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = val;
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but just ran into this issue, thanks @MikeW for the answer, I thinks is complete, the only thing I had to change is the comparison, should be compare to **True** instead of **true**, `var val = (hiddenFieldValueString === "True");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it  without converting into Boolean

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="True" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hf = document.getElementById('<%= hf.ClientID %>');
    if (hf.value == "True") {
        //your code
        hf.value == "False";
    } else {
        //your code
        hf.value == "True";
    }
</script>
```